# Timing occurrence of a word in an audio file

Tags: html, html5-audio

How can i find time of occurrence of each word in an audio file?
Given an audio say xyz.mp3 and there's a word 'lmn' spoken in it. I want to find the time at which 'lmn' is spoken in it without manually playing the audio file.

I will be using this timing information for text audio synchronization in my HTML5 project. If there is any other way to do the same please help.